# bug with checking if first character is int, if it isn't delete that character

Tags: javascript

This piece of code causes Chrome to crash:

```
function forecastTemp(forecast) {
    var end = forecast.indexOf('&'),
        fcWeather = forecast.substring(0, end).length - 3,
        temp = forecast.substring(fcWeather, end);
    if (temp.substr(0) != 0 || 1 || 2 || 3 || 4 || 5 || 6 || 7 || 8 || 9 || '-') {
        do {
            fcWeather = fcWeather + 1;
            temp = forecast.substring(fcWeather, end);
        }
        while (temp.substr(0) != 0 || 1 || 2 || 3 || 4 || 5 || 6 || 7 || 8 || 9 || '-');
    }
    console.log('fcWeather: ' + fcWeather + '');
    console.log('end: ' + end + '');
    console.log('temp: ' + temp + '');
    return (temp);
}
```

Is there a more effective way to see if the first character of a string is an integer or a negative sign and if it isn't to delete that character from the string?

Here are two types of strings that get parsed through this.

Clear. Fog overnight. Low of -2°C with a windchill of -6°C. Winds from the ESE at 15-25 km/h.

Partly cloudy. Low of 3°C. Winds from the ESE at 40-45 km/h.

Comment: Crash how, what exactly happens?

Comment: Formatting code properly helps others to read and understand it.

Comment: Freezes completely. I have my website hosted in my public folder on dropbox if you want to see the problem. It won't cause your whole browser to crash though as chrome has each tab in a new process.
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2887036/New%20Weather/index.html

Comment: @Felix Kling, formatted it properly now, sorry for that.

Comment: Then it seems you have an infinity loop (without looking at your code). *Edit*: `temp.substr(0) != 0 || 1 || 2 || 3 || 4 || 5 || 6 || 7 || 8 || 9 || '-'` will always evaluate to true.

Comment: Also worth noting that the code given **doesn't** make Chrome crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read up on how JavaScript (and most other languages') `==` / `!=` and `||` operators work. This line:

```
if (temp.substr(0) != 0 || 1 || 2 || 3 || 4 || 5 || 6 || 7 || 8 || 9 || '-') {
```

...does **not** check to see if `temp.substr(0)` is one of the values given. It checks if `temp.substr(0) != 0`, or (separately) it checks the value `1` (which is always true), etc. So that condition will always be true.

Since you're doing string/character stuff, the easiest thing would probably be to use `indexOf`:

```
if ("0123456789-".indexOf(temp.charAt(0)) >= 0) {
    // The character matches one of the ones in the string
}
else {
    // It doesn't
}
```

...or a regular expression.

The *general* case for that sort of "is this value any of the following" is a `switch` statement:

```
switch (temp.charAt(0)) {
    case '0':
    case '1':
    case '2':
    case '3':
    case '4':
    case '5':
    case '6':
    case '7':
    case '8':
    case '9':
    case '-':
        // It matches one of the above
        break;
    default:
        // It doesn't
        break;
}
```

...but again, as you're doing string stuff, `indexOf` is a *lot* more concise and easier to read.

Also note that I've put the values in quotes in the `switch` example. If you're comparing strings to strings, you want to be sure that you really do that. The expression `'5' == 5` will consider those two values equal (even though they're not), the `switch` won't. The reason `==` does is that it's the *loose* equality operator. It uses the [abstract equality comparison algorithm](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3), which effectively (in this case) turns the expression into `Number('5') == 5` (**not** `'5' == String(5)`). The `==` operator happily compares values of different types, performing a series of checks and conversions to come up with something to compare (see the link above). `switch` doesn't do that. For one of the `case` clauses of a switch to match the expression you're testing, the values must be of the same type — a switch will never consider `'5'` and `5` to match. `switch` uses the `===` (strict equality) operator, not the `==` (loose equality) operator.

---

Note that I've used `temp.charAt(0)` rather than just `temp.substr(0)` (thanks Felix, I wasn't even looking at that). `temp.substr(0)` just makes a copy of the whole string. You could use `temp.substr(0, 1)` or `temp.charAt(0)`.

Comment: It should be `temp.substr(0, 1)`, otherwise it won't work either.

Comment: @FelixKling: Thanks, I wasn't even looking at that. Added note.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that `charAt` would be even better ;) Enjoy your day!

Comment: I usually have a lot of respect for your answers, but I'm a bit put off by that big ugly switch block. Especially being the first example, and especially considering the OP's objectives. Is there a reason for it?

Comment: I used the indexOf example you provided. It work perfectly, I can't thank you enough for that. All that's left for me to learn is how to make this a recursive function and then read up on operators as you suggested. Again, thank you.

Comment: @Madmartigan: I'm not at my best today (raging cold). Given the OP is using a string, `indexOf` should have been the first one I mentioned. :-) The other is relevant to the general case rather than the string case.